# How can I addView to a LinearLayout in a fragment?

Tags: android, layout, view, fragment, addition

I am trying to add a view to a layout defined in my xml, but it throws a null reference
It is a fragment defined in the app

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manager, container, false);

    LinearLayout layout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttons);
    TextView test = new TextView(getContext());
    test.setText("Test");
    layout.addView(test);

    return rootView;
}
```

FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
tools:context=".ui.planets.ButtonsFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you have to put your linearLayout in fragment_manager.xml not in the FrameLayout

Comment: What's giving you a null reference, the `findViewById` line? Are you inflating the right XML layout file?

Comment: I am so stupid, I made a mistake when inflate the fragment, indeed it is in fragment_buttons.xml, not fragment_manager.xml I'm sorry I wasted your time with this nonsense.